# Tiled image transforming to new profile

Tags: python, gdal

i have a set of tile which was tiled profile of Mercator and proper to tms scheme mechanism.
unfortunately i don't have any tif or georeference table or anything for this. all was tiled with Mercator profile.

do you know any way for transforming them to geodetic profile?
in gdal `re_tile` tool can do this but it needs coordinated tif and projection.

what do you advice me for this huge tiled jpeg file?

thanks for your advice...